# StackExchange Mobile: Use separate CAPTCHA page

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I am on the move a lot and access StackExchange from my mobile device quite frequently. I appreciate the mobile version of the site, but I can't answer any question when it prompts me for a CAPTCHA, because my device is overwhelmed by the amount of content on the page and reboots.

Could you please consider making the CAPTCHAs more mobile friendly?

Comment: How do we know you are not a robot simply trying to bypass the capcha's? ;)

Comment: In all seriousness, anything of the form "disable security under X conditions" is probably not going to work -- captchas exist for a reason

Comment: Because... *I* am that robot!! Cha cha chaaaannnnnn

Comment: I kind of assume it matters if that's a popular modern device: so, what are you using?

Comment: *Could you please consider disabling CAPTCHAs altogether on the mobile version[...]?* Not that I have a say in this, but that's not going to happen. A mobile device can only be identified by its user agent, which is easily spoofable. There's no point in using anti-spam techniques if they're optional.

Comment: Disabling them altogether isn't going to happen. I am a mod and I still get CAPTCHAs. I could see SE "mak[ing] them more mobile friendly" though.

Comment: Actually, @NullUser, being a mod requires captchas even more. Just think about what can happen if [your account is compromised](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html) and there are no limits... That said: do you also get captchas for moderator actions?

Comment: @Arjan They're very rare, but they are there.

Comment: I am a robot. Beep beep beep? In all seriousness, Ihave a Zune HD, the crappiest product ever known to mankind.

Comment: I rolled back because the edited version was not what I meant at all. What I meant was make them more mobile frindly. Sure my Zune's browser stinks, but its all I have. The capatchas redirect to the main site, which overwhelms the browser and causes it to crash. Why redirect to the main site when you don't have to? Embed the capatcha in a regular mobile page with less noise. I don't understand the downvotes, I'm asking you rethink them, not eliminate them. I understand the need for capatchas, but they're not implemented properly on mobile.

Comment: I have the power of buttons. However, this is probably affecting more people then just me.

Comment: This is a bug, it's a non-mobile page on the mobile site.

Comment: Sigh. If you want to roll it back, at least learn that it's spelled CAPTCHA, not "capatcha" :/

Comment: I agree the mobile site should not use the captcha page from the regular site, if that's indeed what's happening. But *where* in your question are you mentioning *that*? I feel you're discussing something completely different in your question than you're suggesting in the comments. *"I'm asking you rethink them, not eliminate them."* No, you're not, you just rolled back the original title that totally asks for getting rid of it. Your title will *never* be honored. And if you think it's a bug, *tag* it as such too please!

Comment: @BoltClock I know that, I'm typing this on my ZUne :)

Comment: @Arjan I changed the focus of the question to reflect what I actually meant and tagged appropriately.

Comment: @Arjan Tru, but that question has no answers.

Comment: That doesn't make it not a duplicate...